# how to find a function to perform a function I wanted

Tags: python

In python program, when I want to perform a function, how to find/check whether are there any existed function in function library. 
just like using Function in Microsolft Office Excel:"Please enter a brief description to describe what you want to do" then we could search the function.

Comment: What about google ?

Comment: The Python help documents. (Sincerely.)

Comment: You can read the documentation or use Google.

Answer (score 2):

Keep looping this until you to learn whatever you want to learn:

1. Open Googles search: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+function
   [image]
2. Add something you want to like `sum complex numbers` and hit the first result:
   [image]
3. Read enterely the first result, to know whether its answers your doudt.
4. If you are not satisfied with the current result, open the next one.
5. Read enterely the current seach result, to know whether its answers your doudt.
6. If you still not satisfied yet and the results seems to be related, go back to the step 4. Else/otherwise go to the step 2 and try different search terms.